# How to compare to list of date in C#?

Tags: c#, list, date, datetime, except

I have two list of date. I have to compare both list and find missing date.
My first list looks like this:

```
2015-07-21
2015-07-22
2015-07-23
2015-07-24
2015-07-25
2015-07-26
2015-07-27
```

My second list looks like this

```
2015-07-21
2015-07-22
2015-07-23
2015-07-25
2015-07-26
2015-07-27
```

I have to find the missing date between the two list :

I tried this

```
var anyOfthem = firstList.Except(secondList);
```

But it didn't work. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Do you have to get the missing dates?

Comment: Yes I have to get date which are missing @LzyPanda

Comment: .Except would return all values except those that are in `secondList`. So it's something completely different from what you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn´t work"? What did you get instead of the desired result?

Comment: @HimBromBeere see my comment ;)

Comment: @SteffenWinkler it's going to return the set difference so in this case a collection with a single item: 2015-07-24. Isn't it what you want Priya? Or do you want this to work both ways?

Comment: @vc, I want a collection with single item. (i.e) the one which is missing

Comment: @vc74 well I wrote it wrong. It's not completely different but it's only half of the picture.

Comment: @Priya, then firstList.Except(secondList); should work. Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you could use `.Except()` and `.Union()` methods :

```
        string[] array1 = 
        {
        "2015-07-21",
        "2015-07-22",
        "2015-07-23",
        "2015-07-24",
        "2015-07-25",
        "2015-07-26",            
        };

        string[] array2 = 
        {
        "2015-07-21",
        "2015-07-22",
        "2015-07-23",            
        "2015-07-25",
        "2015-07-26",
        "2015-07-27"
        };

        var result = array1.Except(array2).Union(array2.Except(array1));

        foreach (var item in result) 
        {
           Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

Output : "2015-07-24", "2015-07-27",

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] array1 = 
{
    "2015-07-21",
    "2015-07-22",
    "2015-07-23",
    "2015-07-24",
    "2015-07-25",
    "2015-07-26",            
};

string[] array2 = 
{
    "2015-07-21",
    "2015-07-22",
    "2015-07-23",            
    "2015-07-25",
    "2015-07-26",
    "2015-07-27"
};

var common = list1.Intersect(list2);
var anyOfThem = list1.Except(common).Concat(list2.Except(common));

foreach (var date in anyOfThem)
    Console.WriteLine(date);

// 2015-07-24
// 2015-07-27
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if one list contains the values from the other list :

```
var anyOfthem = firstList.Where(x => !secondList.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this is exactly what your looking for:

```
var notamatch= firstList.Where(x => !anyOfthem.Any(y => y.yourseconddatename== x.yourfirstdatename));
```